# Skipping compilation of integration tests when unit tests failed in maven

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

Is there a way to skip compilation of integration tests when unit tests fail? I mean, compile (and run) integration tests only in case all unit tests passed.

I am using maven surefire and failsafe plugins.

**EDIT:**
I call maven using the following goals: `mvn clean test integration-test -fae`.

Checked with `verify`, same problem.

Default lifecycle compiles both unit and integration tests in testCompile phase, before running unit tests. I would need to compile integration tests after running unit tests and only if unit tests succesfully passed.

Thanks.

Comment: Usually the build fails if a unit test fails (`mvn clean verify`) ? So I suppose you have configured maven-surefire and/or maven-failsafe in a particular way...?

Comment: I checked with `verify` and the problem is similar: I need avoid compiling integration tests when unit tests fail.

Comment: If you just use as I suggested `mvn clean verify` the life cycle will be stopped if a unit test fails...which means also the it's will not even compiled?... Furthermore `mvn clean test integration-test` shows that you haven't correctly understood the life cycle because using `test` and afterward `integration-test` repeats several steps ...

Comment: Thanks. I reviewed the life cycle. In test-compile phase both unit tests and integration tests are compiled. That test-compile phase is run with verify and integration-test as well. Anyway, since my problem is not properly formulated, I will create a new one titled: Skipping compilation of integration tests when unit tests failed in maven

Comment: So after you have reviewed the life cycle this will give me more information about your project structure. That means your integration tests are in the same module (I suppose named like `*IT.java` or alike).. and now the final part. If they are within the same module you can't prevent that IT's will be compiled if unit tests fail. This could only be achieved if you move the IT's to a separate module. The question which arises based on that: Why would you like to prevent compiling of IT's if unit tests fail? What is the real problem here?

Comment: You are right @khmarbaise. My project is a multimodule project with unit and integration tests in each module, and cannot be separated. Some unit tests check the presence of files and resources needed to compile IT's. So, I should prevent compiling of IT's when unit tests fail. Furthermore, I am building the project in Jenkins so when unit tests fail the build status should be UNESTABLE  (it is the expected result in Jenkins). But since IT tests are also compiled, IT's compilation fails, and the final build status is FAILURE (compilation error) instead of UNESTABLE (some tests failed).

Comment: I checked using different <executions>  for [compiling sources and tests separately]( https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html#example-configuring-compile-and-testcompile-mojos-separately) but IT’s and unit test are compiled together, as expected. I guess my use case would need a new, not supported goal such as `integrationTestCompile` in the maven compiler to solve my problem using executions.

Comment: First why will compilation of IT's fail So you have to fix your compilation issues first?  Multi module can not being changed/separated sounds a bit strange? Of course you can separate the integration test from the unit test and move them into separate module. Furthermore if unit tests using external resources (files etc.) means those tests are not unit test anymore. Very strange. If you have compilation issue in your IT's then this has to be fixed first. After that get your unit tests running and finally get your IT's running. It sounds more and more your workflow is a bit unusual